# How to update a list view taken from a database with no user accounts

Tags: android, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database, android-listview

my current app takes customer details, sends them to a real time firebase database, a switch activity button takes the user to a customer information page where it displays all data in the database, i am wondering if its possible to update specific users without using authentication to log in as its the shop owner using this app not customers.

All videos i have found use the firebase authentication which allows for user details to be updated, but my app lists all database data as no specfic logged in user.

below is my class that recieves the database information and displays it on screen

```
public class CustomerDataRetrieved extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listView;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    Firebase firebase;
    List<CustomerName> customerNameList;
    public static final String Database_Path = "Customer Details";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_customer_data_retrieved);


        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        firebase = new Firebase(Firebase_Server_URL);

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Database_Path);

        customerNameList = new ArrayList<>();



    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot customerSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    CustomerName customers = customerSnapshot.getValue(CustomerName.class);
                    customerNameList.add(customers);
                }
                CustomerInfoAdapter customerInfoAdapter = new CustomerInfoAdapter(CustomerDataRetrieved.this,customerNameList);
                listView.setAdapter(customerInfoAdapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

If this helps, this is an image of my Customer Information activity which uses a listview to display all the data from the database, and i am wondering if its possible to update specific information from each user if required through my app, for instance if the customers quoted price changes, or contact number has changed

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to update a specific node in the database you need to know something that identifies that node. When storing user data that is typically the UID of the user. But if you're not using Firebase Authentication, it can be anything else that identifies the user(s) whose node you want to update.

In addition to to knowing the path, you must also have permission to update the node. This is why you often see Firebase Authentication's UID being used, as it allows securing access to the data based on who the user is. If you're not using Firebase Authentication, you'll have to come up with a different scheme to protect your data.

Comment: when you said anything else that identifies the users whose node you wish to update, how would i go about this? technically all the customer data that is entered is using the same fields, i.e first name, bike collection date, quoted repair price etc... how would i ensure that it is the correct users say contact number that is being updated? as all i get is a list of everything in the database?

Comment: You will need to "know" something that uniquely identifies them. Normally that'd be their UID, which Firebase ensures that it can't be spoofed. If you're not using Firebase authentication you're on your own for that.

Comment: when using firebase authentication, would it be possible to login with say the owner (one account), then be able to select specific customer details and edit anyone you choose? or does customer details require each customer to have their own login to be able to update their information?

Comment: You can appoint a certain user as an "application administrator" and grant them different access based on that.